# deployment/auth-mongo-depl: container auth-mongo is waiting to start: mongo can't be pulled

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, deployment, pull-request

This is my `auth-depl.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: tester/auth
          env:
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: 'mongodb://auth-mongo-srv:27017/auth'
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

And the following is `auth-mongo-depl.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-mongo
          image: mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-mongo
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

When I run `skaffold dev` it gives me the following error:

```
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: container auth-mongo is waiting to start: mongo can't be pulled
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-64f5f58669-dw4hg: container auth-mongo is waiting to start: mongo can't be pulled
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl failed. Error: container auth-mongo is waiting to start: mongo can't be pulled.
```

The `mongo` service is up and running and I can run `mongo` command on the terminal. It also starts and runs on it's default `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017` address. I use Windows 10 and Docker-Desktop.

Let me know if more information needs to be added.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and this was how I resolved it. I went to my Docker Desktop app (Mac) and did a clean-up of all the docker images. I basically deleted all the images which also include mongo image.

[image]

[image]

Then I ran `skaffold dev` and all the images were built again, and a fresh copy of mongo was added to my Docker Desktop app. Now, my code started successfully without mongo error. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (took me 3 hours to figure out) and what I had to do was set a local or global default repo in the Skaffold context:

Global
`skaffold config set default-repo <your-dockerhub-repo>`

Local Project
`skaffold dev --default-repo <myrepo>`

Also in my skaffold.yaml I had to set push to true:

```
build:
  local:
    push: true
```

More info found in Skaffold Docs:
https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/image-registries/

Answer (score 0):

I think the common solution is to pull the mongo image in Docker Hub to your local machine and then try to run skaffold dev again

Comment: You answer would be better to posted as a comment rather than a post.

Answer (score 0):

skaffold by default tries to retrieve image from docker hub. If you are ok with getting the image from docker hub  just add this config to your skaffold.yaml file but make sure to push your image to docker hub for this to work

```
build:
  local:
    push: true
```

If you don't want skaffold to retrieve image from docker hub and want to do it locally. Install minikube and run minikube start from your terminal and change the config of your skaffold.yaml to

```
build:
  local:
    push: false
```

After changing the skaffold.yaml file, Run skaffold dev
It should probably fix your error.